# c# generics and inheritance

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I'm getting a compilation error on following code:

```
public abstract class DbHandler<T>
{
    public abstract bool Save(T obj);
    ...
}
```

and its implementing class:

```
 public class SpaghettiTableDb : DbHandler<SpaghettiTable>
 {
    public bool Save(SpaghettiTable obj)
    {
        return false;
    }
    ...
 }
```

The error is :

```
'SpaghettiTableDb' does not implement inherited abstract member 'SeatPicker.DbHandler<SeatPicker.SpaghettiTable>.Save(SeatPicker.SpaghettiTable)'
```

But I think it does, so I'm not sure why I'm receiving this error.

(SpaghettiTable is just a class with some properties, nothing more)

Any help?

Comment: Have you cleaned and rebuilt your solution?

Comment: Visual Studio does have intellisense - so try hovering over the base class with your mouse, you'll see a little drop down, click on that and select "Implement ...".  It will define it for you.

Comment: As an aside: plugins like ReSharper are very useful in cases like this, they can generate the correct boilerplate for you.

Comment: @millimoose vanilla Visual Studio can auto-generate the boiler plate code as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the `override` keyword.  Otherwise you're not implementing the abstract base class and just creating a "new" separate method on the subclass.

```
public override bool Save(SpaghettiTable obj)
{
    return false;
}
```

Think of `abstract` methods just like `virtual` methods that you override.  The only difference is that you *force* subclasses to provide an implementation of that method whereas `virtual` methods provide their own implementation that subclasses can *optionally* override with their own implementation.

EDIT: Additionally, if you want to make your life easier in Visual Studio, you can right-click (or `ctrl+.`) on the inheritance declaration and choose "implement abstract class" (or something like that, I don't have VS with me right now) which will automatically create all the overridden methods for you.

`public class SpaghettiTableDb : DbHandler<SpaghettiTable> //right-click on "DbHandler"`

Alternatively, in the empty code space within your class, you can start typing "override", then the IntelliSense will list all overridable members from the base class and when you pick one it will automatically write a default implementation for you.

EDIT:
Just to extend on what you have in your code, without the `override` keyword, you are creating a new method that belongs to your subclass and not overriding the base class. When you call that method but from the context of using the base class, it won't call your subclass implementation since it doesn't override the base method.

Consider the following classes. (I'm using virtual instead of abstract just so it compiles and have it simpler)

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public virtual void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base print");
    }

    public virtual void AnotherPrint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base another print");
    }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public override void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sub print");
    }

    public void AnotherPrint()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("sub another print");
    }
}
```

Note that `SubClass.AnotherPrint` does *not* override `BaseClass.AnotherPrint`.

And when you use code like:

```
SubClass mySub = new SubClass();

mySub.Print(); //sub print
mySub.AnotherPrint(); //sub another print

BaseClass myBase = mySub;

myBase.Print(); //sub print
myBase.AnotherPrint(); //base another print
```

Note that through the code, `mySub` and `myBase` both point to the *same object*, but one is typed as `SubClass` and the other as `BaseClass`.  When the runtime calls `myBase.Print()`, it can easily check the inheritance of the classes and see that `SubClass` has overridden the `Print` method and calls the `SubClass` implementation.  However, since `SubClass.AnotherPrint` wasn't explicitly marked with `override`, the runtime/compiler considers that to be a *completely different method* with no link to the `BaseClass.AnotherPrint` method.  Thus the runtime sticks with the base class implementation.  When your instance is typed as the `SubClass` though, the compiler does see that you're pointing to that new method and essentially not to the base implementation.

Comment: @StevenLemmens You're welcome! I just added some more info about what's going on behind the scenes if you'd like to read up on it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `override` keyword when implementing abstract methods or overriding virtual methods.

```
public override bool Save(SpaghettiTable obj)
{
    return false;
}
```